# Fiksu SDK Integration

Tags: android, ios, tracking, event-tracking

I am trying to implement Fiksu SDK for Android and iOS.

I am able to add code to track registration and purchase :

```
FiksuTrackingManager.uploadRegistration(Context, FiksuTrackingManager.RegistrationEvent.EVENT1);

FiksuTrackingManager.uploadPurchase(Context, FiksuTrackingManager.PurchaseEvent.EVENT1, 0, "USD");
```

In iOS i am able to get the logs in the console, but in android i am only getting logs which event is called.How can i check the logs in Android ?

Also how to track the app events in Fiksu dashboard ?

They have also mentioned to add `client id` , from where will i get the client id ?

if any one has implemented it please guide me how to proceed ?

Comment: Can you please tell me Where did you get the fiksu android sdk?

Comment: Refer this link - http://www.fiksu.com/

Answer (score 2):

this might be too late but it may help someone that comes across this post.

I just had to integrate the Fiksu SDK for android for a client and face similar issues when testing.

**How can i check the logs in Android ?**

If the SDK has been properly installed you should be able to see some logs like below which means the events have been succesfully sent to their server.

```
11-25 10:04:31.010  21588-23132/ D/FiksuTracking? Event: Resume
11-25 10:04:32.320  21588-23132/ D/FiksuTracking? Successfully uploaded tracking information.
11-25 10:05:40.500  21588-23383/ D/FiksuTracking? Event: Purchase
11-25 10:05:42.180  21588-23383/ D/FiksuTracking? Successfully uploaded tracking information.
```

**how to track the app events in Fiksu dashboard ?**

This part is quite annoying as they don't have a way to create Apps in the dashboard and link them to your android app so you can see your events coming through. Instead you have to actually perform the test and send them an email for someone from Fiksu to check their servers and track your events.

These are the test steps as per their documentation:

- Download and install your application on an Android device and perform your tests.
- Fill a form they have and send it via email to their support team.
- Someone will get back to you confirming if they have received your events.

**They have also mentioned to add client id , from where will i get the client id ?**

The clientId is just an identifier for your users within your app. In other words you can set that to whatever you want (e.i. email address). The suggestion is to set this after a user has registered or logged in in your app.

```
FiksuTrackingManager.setClientId(Context, "XXX");
```

Based on their documentation: "Where XXX would be the ID you want to send and can be any alphanumeric string up to 64 characters long. All events sent after this call is made would send the Client ID that has been set. If you call setClientID again it will overwrite whatever was there before. However the first Client ID sent with an event will be the Client ID that is in the export on the Fiksu Client Dashboard and it will not get updated."

**if any one has implemented it please guide me how to proceed ?**

So to sum up below are the steps to integrate the Fiksu SDK for android.

1. Downlaod the SDK.
2. Add the SDK jar to your project.
3. Set the isntall receiver (Only if you want to track app installs). NOTE that they expect to be the only receiver in the AndroidManifest.xml file. If you are using other third party SDKs to track the same you either:

**Use fiksu to forward the intent:**

```
<receiver android:name="com.fiksu.asotracking.InstallTracking"
android:exported="true">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
</intent-filter>
<!-- Forward to other receivers -->
<meta-data android:name="forward.1"
android:value="com.google.android.apps.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver" />
<meta-data android:name="forward.2" android:value="com.mypackage.thirdparty.MdotmReceiver" />
</receiver>
```

**Or set the below flag in your AndroidManifest and have another install receiver forward it to the fiksu SDK.**

```
<meta-data android:name="FiksuDisableReceiverCheck" android:value="true" />
```

4. Set the permissions in your AndroidManifest.

   android.permission.INTERNET

   android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
5. Initialize the SDK. Normally on your Application onCreate() method.

   FiksuTrackingManager.initialize(this);
6. Setting up Google Play Services on your project.